# Python Tortoise-ORM: use related model field in __str__

Tags: python, orm, python-asyncio, aiohttp, tortoise-orm

I'm developing an API service with AIOHTTP, I try to integrate some async ORM, and the first candidate is Tortoise-ORM.
In a Django project I have lots of linked models with `__str__` method like the following:

```py
from tortoise.models import Model
from tortoise import fields

class Department(Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    title = fields.TextField()
    upper = fields.ForeignKeyField('models.Department', related_name='children')

    def __str__(self):
        if self.upper is not None:
            return f'{self.id} Department {self.title} of {self.upper.title}'
        else:
            return f'{self.id} Department {self.title}, head'

class Employee(Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    name = fields.TextField()
    dep = fields.ForeignKeyField('models.Department', related_name='employees')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}. Employee {self.name} of {self.dep.title}'
```

So that each object shows it's related models in description. But in Tortoise I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'title'

I guess it's not possible to await the query in the `__str__` method. So, is it possible at all use a field of related model to create object representation using Tortoise-ORM?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Tortoise-ORM` does not automatically retrieve related data for the model object from the database, until one asks it to do that. It just generates `QuerySet` object for related data without actually hitting the database.

To actually get data you need to use `prefetch_related()` or `fetch_related()` before printing of your objects. [Documentation](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/query.html) says:

> General rule about how `prefetch_related()` works is that each level of depth of related models produces 1 additional query, so `.prefetch_related('events__participants')` will produce two additional queries to fetch your data.

Like so:

```py
    emp_one = await Employee.filter(name="Emp_1").prefetch_related("dep").first()
    print(emp_one)

    emp_two = await Employee.filter(name="Emp_2").first()
    await emp_two.fetch_related("dep")
    print(emp_two)
```